# How to use shortcode_atts() on a tax_query?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have this shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('menu2','menu2');

function menu2($atts, $content = ''){
ob_start();

$options = shortcode_atts( array(
    'post_type' => 'menu',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'menu_type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'lunch_menu'
            )
        )
    ), $atts);

$query = new WP_Query($options);
```

My code above is for a shortcode, which is used like this:

```
[menu2 terms="wines"]Wines[/menu2]
```

`lunch_menu` should be replaced with `wines`, but it doesn’t. What should I change?

Comment: This pretty much looks like the same question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84607/custom-taxonomy-and-tax-query

Answer (score 0):

You run `shortcode_atts()` on the wrong array. You need `tax_query`, but you are using the complete array.

I guess you need something like this:

```
$tax_query = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'menu_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'lunch_menu'
        )
    ), 
    $atts
);

$options = array(
    'post_type'      => 'menu',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'      => $tax_query
);
```

And `'posts_per_page' => -1` is very, very dangerous. What happens when your user has 100k matching posts? Don’t do that.